# Fazer if em uma tag HTML para adicionar ou não atributo "checked"

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, if

Estou desenvolvendo com o `.Net Core Razor` e estou setando uma `string` no meu `GET` e preciso que, de acordo com o que esta `string` seja (no caso "true" ou "false"), o `checkbox` seja marcado ou não.

A `string` está sendo enviada e recebida, mas não estou conseguindo tratar a resposta para marcar ou não este `checkbox`.

**Estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dt_ini" name="checkDataInicial" onchange="liberarDataHora()" @HttpContext.Session.GetString("CheckDI") =="true" ? checked>
```

Mas este `if` que eu estou fazendo não está funcionando como eu quero. 
O que eu quero é que se `@HttpContext.Session.GetString("CheckDI")` for igual a `true`, adicione o atributo `checked` àquela `tag`.

**O que está aparecendo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém aí tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer?

**EDIT:** Eu consegui resolver o meu problema mas não como eu gostaria. Oque eu fiz foi mudar a `String` que é enviada no `GET`. Onde era "true" eu coloquei "checked" e onde era "false" eu coloquei ""(vazio); aí minha tag ficou assim:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dt_ini" name="checkDataInicial" onchange="liberarDataHora()" @HttpContext.Session.GetString("CheckDI")>
```

Funcionou, mas não é bem como eu gostaria. Enfim, se alguém aí souber como posso fazer esse if, deixa aí na resposta por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi direito, o `Html.Raw()` pode te ajudar:

```
@( suaVariavel == "true" ? Html.Raw("checked"): Html.Raw(""))
```

Comment: Pode mostrar como ficou por favor?

Comment: Peço desculpas, sua resposta está correta. Funcionou perfeitamente. O erro foi eu que cometi. Parece que o código não compilou corretamente, quando atualizei para o seu código. Muito bom